# Key mapping to multiple values

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash

In Ruby, I want to have something like

```
my_hash =  {:a => [b,c,h], :d => [e,f,g]..}
```

instead of 
`my_hash= {:a => b ,:a => c ,:a => h , :d => e , :d=> f ,:d => g }`. 
I cannot use arrays as value because I want to get the key of the value ie 
my_hash.key(c) should return a . 
Does any body know how to do this with ruby hash class or is there any other data structure.
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you can't map it the other way? `{ b => :a, c => :a ...}`

Comment: I can but just wanted to avoid code repetition. There will around 10 keys mapping to a , around the same number to b ...so was looking for a better approach !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the hash is probably your best bet but, heh, just for kicks...

```
class Hash
  def key_array_with(val)
    self.keys.select { |k| k.include?(val) }.first
  end
end

h = {[:b,:c,:h] => :a, [:e,:f,:g] => :d}
h[h.key_array_with(:c)]
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Your solution worked . This might be a stupid question but the method defined should return the key ie [:b,:c,:h] why is it returning :a ??

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the inline code example to display properly but it does return [:b,:c,:h] when you do h.key_array_with(:c). It only returns :a when you key the hash with h[h.key_array_with(:c)].

Comment: yeah..thanks . i accidentally skipped the h[] part of the example you gave. Now I understood . Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You should have the keys and values the other way around.

```
{b => :a, c => :a, h => :a, e => :d, f => :d, g => :d, ...}
```

Comment: I guess reversing is the only option i have if i want to use Hash. But for the reason stated above in the comment , I am looking for a data structure which can support that